# ejecutar cmd desde java

Tags: java, cmd

Quiero descargar un archvio desde una pagina web mediante comandos bat que se ejecutaran desde dentro de JAva esto para hacer el boton que sea de actualizar la aplicacion.

que cuando presione el boton desde java el programa ejecutara los comandos bat y descargara el archivo y lo ejecutara para actualizarlo

pero el problema es que no se como acomodarlo

en el Bat lo tengo a si y si me funciona bien

```html
@echo off

bitsadmin /transfer Actualizacion/download /priority normal ^
  "http://servidorejemplo.com/ghjgjghjgjghj/Smi-archivo.rar" "C:\Users\salud\downloads\Smi-archivo.rar"

start "actualizacion_prueba" "C:\Users\salud\Downloads\Smi-archivo.rar"
```

como mencione estos comando funcionan muy bien desde el archvio Bat, pero desde JAVA no se como colocarlo ya que he intentado de varias formas y no funona.

tambien intente ejecutar el Bat desde Java y si funciono , pero quiero que esos comandos no se vean y esten en el archivo java.

se podra hacer eso o no me queda de otra mas que ejecutar el archivo bat desde Java.

```html
String command = "cmd /c @echo off bitsadmin /transfer midescarga /download /priority normal ^ 'http://saludbcs.gob.mx/ASg34lpU_34SDtuVX97/SINBA-SEUL-P.rar' 'C:\\Users\\salud\\downloads\\SINBA-SEUL-P.rar' start /wait 'Actualizacion' 'C:\\Users\\salud\\downloads\\SINBA-SEUL-P.rar'";
                     Process child = tiempoEjecucion.exec(command);
```

a sii es como lo tengo en JAva y no pasa nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en esta imagen lo que esta comentado es lo que he tratado de hacer.

y lo que he conseguido es que me diga en una Alert que "@echo no esta definido", otra que no se encuentra el archvio @echo y la otra es que me abre el cmd como si lo hubiera abierto manualmente que se queda esperando a que le escribas un comando y ya.

espero y si se pueda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pos con la novedad que ya pude jejejej.

```
cmd.exe /C start bitsadmin /transfer midescarga /download /priority normal http://servidorejemplo.com/ghjgjghjgjghj/Smi-archivo.rar C:\\Users\\salud\\downloads\\Smi-archivo.rar
```

y asi quedo ahora eso lo pongo dentro de un boton y ya tengo mi boton para descragar una actualizacion del programa